# How to plot a cumulative histogram in pyplot with logarithmic xscale only

Tags: python, matplotlib

This plots logarithmic xscale AND yscale. Can't seem to figure out how to plot logarithmic xscale only.

```
plt.hist(data, bins=10, cumulative=True, log=True)
```

Comment: Drop the `log=True` parameter on the histogram plot and use the `set_xscale("log")` of your axes object.

Comment: this results in unequal bar widths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the log in the y axis with the following:

```
plt.gca().set_yscale('linear')
```

Or press the L key when the figure is in focus.

However, your `hist()` with `log=True` does not plot a logarithmic x axis. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, bins=10, ...)
>
> bins:
>      Either an integer number of bins or a sequence giving the bins. If bins is an integer, bins + 1 bin edges will be returned, consistent with numpy.histogram() for numpy version >= 1.3, and with the new = True argument in earlier versions. **Unequally spaced bins are supported if bins is a sequence.**

So if you just set `bins=10` they will be equally spaced, which is why when you set the xscale to log they have decreasing widths. To get equally spaced bins in a log xscale you need something like:

```
plt.hist(x, bins=10**np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

Comment: You're right, it doesn't set xscale to log. And you're right about xscale and unequal bins etc. Good answer thanks.